# Unable to find where external IP address is being blocked (nginx, nodejs, linksys router)

Tags: networking, server, webserver, nginx

So while it's not ideal, I currently have a web server running Ubuntu 14.04 behind a Linksys router. On the router, I have forwarded ports 22, 80, and 435 for SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS respectively.

Now, running a very simple nginx reverse proxy to route port 80 to a very simple node script listening on local port 3001, I am able to open up a web browser from anywhere on my local network and access the server's public ip on port 80 and get the correct response.

As soon as I try to connect to the same public ip on my iPhone's signal (easiest method for me to use an external ip), I get an error saying that the "network connection was lost." I have tried disabling ufw, but this is my current ufw status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I just recently enabled the `Nginx Full` profile in hopes that it may help, but it has not.

Running `tcpdump -i em1 port 80 -s 0 -w capture.cap`, attempting to connect on my iphone, and then running `tcpick -C -yP -r capture.cap` gives the following results:

```
Timeout for connections is 600
tcpick: reading from capture.cap
1      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:12649 > LOCAL_IP:http
1      SYN-RECEIVED   IPHONE_IP:12649 > LOCAL_IP:http
2      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:12649 > LOCAL_IP:http
3      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:12649 > LOCAL_IP:http
4      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:21998 > LOCAL_IP:http
4      SYN-RECEIVED   IPHONE_IP:21998 > LOCAL_IP:http
5      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:21998 > LOCAL_IP:http
6      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:21998 > LOCAL_IP:http
7      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:9256 > LOCAL_IP:http
7      SYN-RECEIVED   IPHONE_IP:9256 > LOCAL_IP:http
8      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:9256 > LOCAL_IP:http
9      SYN-SENT       IPHONE_IP:9256 > LOCAL_IP:http
tcpick: done reading from capture.cap
```

and here is my very basic nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mgmcdermott.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_read_timeout 180s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My hunch is telling me that because I can access the website locally, then it must be my router blocking external requests, however, I am able to SSH remotely through the router and have tried disabling all firewalls with no luck.

I have knowledge in programming and basic knowledge in server-side setups, however I am new to doing a fresh install with Ubuntu and nginx behind a router.

*I am willing to completely wipe Ubuntu and reinstall fresh if needed*

I'll conclude by mentioning that I am a little inexperienced when it comes to posting StackExchange questions. I've read a thousand of them, but have rarely found something to post that isn't already here, so please bare with me if I missed something.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Using the traceroute command, it shows a network timeout with a !X meaning "communication administratively prohibited":

```
1-4. Pings across work network
5. * * *
6. * * *
7. * * *
...
19. * * * LAST_PINGED_IP_AT_STEP_4 1.491 ms !X
...
```

I see that the !X shows up, meaning *communication administratively prohibited*, not sure if that helps.

Even more information...

```
$ sudo netstat -tclp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      1339/mysqld
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      1301/nginx
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1262/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1262/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:3001               [::]:*                  LISTEN      1395/node
```

Comment: Tried traceroute command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging, I found that a request to port 80 was being held up by:

ool-4353e70a.dyn.optonline.net (67.83.231.10)

This ip resolves to my ISP. Turns out Optimum blocks port 80 unless you upgrade your service. *facepalm*

> [From the docs](http://optimum.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2140/~/port-80-and-optimum-online). Activation of Port 80 is currently available with Optimum Online Ultra 50, Optimum Online Ultra 75 or Optimum Online Ultra 101.